# Animated Gif image not uploading correctly

Tags: images, uploads

Started today, I tried many times to upload a gif image and inserted it. 
Wordpress gives this[image]

But when I checked media library, I found it there attached with a post.

These are error logs:

```
[Mon Sep 16 01:47:19 2013] [error] Script timed out before returning headers: php53.cgi
[Mon Sep 16 01:55:28 2013] [error] ModSecurity: Error reading request body: End of file found [hostname "xxxxx.com"] [uri "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"] [unique_id "UjbHgNBhnx0AACVfm-sAAAAH"]
[Mon Sep 16 01:55:28 2013] [error] (70014)End of file found: Error reading request entity data
```

Please tell how to resolve this?

Comment: look for any `.htaccess` issue. I had similar problem turned out it was faulty `.htaccess` on `wp-content` directory. Can you access any previously uploaded image?

Comment: My .htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: put on the question. is there any `.htaccess` on `wp-content` directory? Give it a check. Sometimes security plugins set it up. Also try disabling all plugins and use a default theme.

Comment: yes, in uploads.. it contains this,..### Generated. DO NOT modify!!! ###
SetHandler no-handler
################################################

Comment: hmm.. try creating a backup of it (download) then delete or rename the file and see if the problem remains. Also Can you upload other files like jpg, png etc?

Comment: yes, other files are easily uploaded.One more thing when I upload a gallery mix of gif, png, jpg.There is no error at all.

Comment: Mod security is known to cause issues with WP, although I hadn't encountered this specific one. The resolution is typically to have hosting support determine problematic rule and disable it.